# Is it legal to put an iframe website on a android application?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-play, google-play-services

i want to know if is it legal to put an iframe of a website in my android application and put it on play store ? 
for example i want to put in my application just this code
`<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>`

Comment: what about this website ? where user can Login in there account         
`moutamadris.men.gov.ma/Fr/espaceprive/Pages/Accueil.asp`                  is that legal?

Answer (score 1):

It's depends of the website if you have the permissions to include the web , it's should not be a problem, just you have to worry about your content.

Comment: what about this website ? where user can Login in there account `moutamadris.men.gov.ma/Fr/espaceprive/Pages/Accueil.asp` is that legal?

Answer (score 0):

To display a website you should do it through webview in Android app

Comment: what about this website ? where user can Login in there account `moutamadris.men.gov.ma/Fr/espaceprive/Pages/Accueil.asp` is that legal?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a browser and post it on the play store, so it is okay to display the content of other sites. It just depends on the presentation and context of that information.

For example I would not embed some site and present it as my original content, or try to sell the content.

Comment: what about this website ? where user can Login in there account `moutamadris.men.gov.ma/Fr/espaceprive/Pages/Accueil.asp` is that legal?